# Finding operator norm on $c_0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $c_0$ be the space of sequences $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to 0$ with the norm
$$\|x\|_\infty=\sup_n|x_n|$$

Let $(a_{ij})_{ij}$, $i,j\geq 1
$ such that $$ \sup_{i\geq1}\sum_{ j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|<\infty.$$
Let $T:c_0\to c_0$ with $Tx=(Tx)_n$ with
$$(Tx)_i=\sum_{ j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j.$$
The aim here is to compute the operator norm of $T$
In fact, for $x\in c_0$ we have
$$|(Tx)_i|\leq \sum_{ j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}||x_j|\leq \|x\|_\infty \sup_{i\geq1}\sum_{ j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$$
Hence,
$$\|Tx\|_\infty\leq \|x\|_\infty \sup_{i\geq1}\sum_{ j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$$

So that $$\|T\|\leq  \sup_{i\geq1}\sum_{ j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$$

The main difficulty is to show the reverse inequality
$$\|T\|\geq  \sup_{i\geq1}\sum_{ j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|.$$

Also, How to show that  bounded operator on $c_0$ are of the form $(Tx)_i=\sum_{ j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1509702/42969

Answer (score 1):

Fix $i$ and $N$. Let $x_j=\frac {|a_{ij}|} {a_{ij}}$ for $j \leq N$, $0$ for $j >N$ where $\frac 0 0$ is interpreted as $0$.

Then $\|x\|\leq 1$ and $(Tx)_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} |a_{ij}|$. By the definition of $\|T\|$ it follows that $\|T\| \geq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} |a_{ij}|$. This is true for each $i,N$ so $\|T\| \geq \sup_i \sum_j |a_{ij}|$.

For a given $T$ just take $a_{ij}$ as the $i-$th component of $T(e_j)$ where $e_j$ is the sequence which has $1$ in $j-$th position and $0$ elsewhere.